# How can I use Haskell Memoize to solve LCS?

Tags: haskell, memoization

Here is the code:

```
import Data.Function.Memoize

main = do
    let 
        f 0 0 = 0
        f 0 _ = 0
        f _ 0 = 0
        f n m = if a !! n == b !! m
            then 1 + f' (n-1) (m-1)
            else max (f' (n-1) m) (f' n (m-1))

        f' = memoize2 $ f
    print $ length a
    print $ length b
    print $ f (length a - 1) (length b - 1)
    where
        a = "1234helloworld2ffdfdfdf32rg4364jm5"
        b = "03424helloworldfdfdfdfd4353645645jnt"
```

But the problem is I cannot write the function globally where strings a and b are passed to it as arguments. It seems if I rewrite

`f n m`

to

`f a b n m`

and

`f' = memoize4 f`

the function will speed down.

How can I pass arguments that should not be used in memoization to functions that use memoize?

so I write my global function like this and it does work!

But how can I accumulate the common string it finds and get the final result with this function?

```
lcs a b = f (length a - 1) (length b - 1)
  where
        f 0 0 = 0
        f 0 _ = 0
        f _ 0 = 0
        f n m = if a !! n == b !! m
            then (1 + f' (n-1) (m-1))
            else max (f' (n-1) m) (f' n (m-1))
        f' = memoize2 $ f
```

Comment: Show us what your version with a global f looks like.

Comment: You need to write the global f so it has a local function with two arguments that you can use memoize2 on.

Comment: I see. But how can I accumulate the common string along with the calculation.

Comment: Your original function just printed the final result.  If you want to do more things you need to have information in the function result.